# In The Avengers, how is it possible that the Hulk can overpower the god Loki?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, the-incredible-hulk, loki

Hulk versus Loki was a funny clip in the movie *The Avengers*, but Loki is a god, isn't he? How can the Hulk be so much stronger than him?

Comment: I agree. What is your question?

Comment: I mean Loki is a god, right?  Does it seem weird that a god is being out-powered by a non-god like Hulk?

Comment: Loki isn't a god. He's an alien with greater strength and stamina than a human, and he has access to technology so advanced that we call it magic. The Hulk also has greater strength and stamina than a (regular) human

Comment: OK. But in this site - http://theavengersmovie.wikia.com/, he is considered a god - Loki Laufeyson is an Asgardian prince, the God of Mischief.  Maybe I'm just confused, associating Loki to the Norse mythology rather than as character in Avengers, but it seems in Avengers, he is also a god.  I have same notion with his brother Thor.

Comment: I think I'm just going to make this into an answer; it's going to be easier

Comment: I think that the one who edited my question, did made the question a little bit better.

Comment: Also: [Is Loki a God?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/55328/21267)

Comment: Also: [Loki's Powers](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/53519/21267)

Comment: @BlueDeeper : That was me.  You're welcome.  :-)

Comment: Hulk Answer: PUNY GOD, PUNY GOD!

Comment: @Thaddeus: Nice.  :-)

Comment: the wikia you linked is not an official site, nor is anything referenced or sourced. anything on it should be taken with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Loki isn't a god. Odin says this explicitly in *Thor: The Dark World*:

> **Odin:** We are not Gods. We are born, we live, we die, just as humans do.
>
> **Loki:** Give or take five thousand years.
>
> <sup><sub>[*Thor: The Dark World* (2013)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1981115/quotes?item=qt2082694)</sub></sup>

However, a more intuitive answer to the question would be: **sure, but Hulk is *also* a god.**

The Asgardians are the source of Norse mythology on Earth; this is referenced a few times in *Thor*, but a particularly interesting example is when Fandral is trying to talk Thor out of invading Jotunheim:

> **Fandral:** This isn't like a journey to Earth, where you summon a little lightning and thunder and the mortals worship you as a god. This is Jotunheim.
>
> <sup><sub>[*Thor* (2011)](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Thor.html)</sub></sup>

This line suggests that Thor and his, for lack of a better word, entourage have visited Earth in the past, and there inspired the Norse myths about Thor and Loki. So in that sense Loki *is* the God of Mischief: he's the inspiration for the mythological figure.

It's understandable why primitive humans would have regarded Loki (and certainly Thor, with his lightning rod hammer) as a god:

- He has strength, stamina, and reflexes beyond that of even the strongest human
- He can create illusory versions of himself that appear to act independently of the real Loki
- He appears in a column of rainbow-coloured light that comes down out of the sky (or he would have to early humans)

The first of these advantages is biological. The other two are technological, and he has to use them consciously. But he's not indestructible; he can be hurt by a sufficiently powerful force (Thor gets pretty banged up by the Destroyer in *Thor*), and he **can** be killed (as [has been covered on this site before](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31377/avengers-movie-loki-and-thor-immortality-test?rq=1)).

Now let's look at the Hulk:

- Stronger than a normal man
- Practically invulnerable. He *can* be hurt, but it takes someone like Thor or Iron Man to do it; he shrugs off bullets like they're mosquito bites, and even getting brained by Thor's hammer just makes him madder
- Surprisingly quick for such a big guy

Drop the Hulk into 10th century Norway, and I guarantee you he'd be taken as a god.

But all of this is building up to the answer to the question: **how could Hulk overpower Loki**.

Easily:

- **Hulk is physically stronger than Loki.** Loki isn't all-powerful, he just thinks he is. Gamma-irradiated muscles beat out Frost Giant physiology
- **Loki wasn't expecting an attack.** Loki isn't omnipotent at the best of the times, although he's generally clever enough to look it. But this isn't the "best of times"; Loki is in the middle of a minor breakdown, and is clearly not operating at peak efficiency.

So the Hulk takes advantage of a moment where Loki isn't fully capable of deploying his tricks and misdirections, and beats him with sheer brute force.

And Tony's floor.

Comment: OK. Thank you for the explanation.  So this means, in the Avenger storyline, the aliens Thor and Loki became the gods perceived by earthlings that soon became part of the Norse mythology.

Comment: @BlueDeeper : That's exactly what he is saying.  Emphasis on *perceived*.

Comment: This answer, it's so beautiful. Thank you. (Seriously.)

Comment: See Also: [Is Loki actually a god?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/55329/2765)

Comment: @Blake. +1 for a great answer.  Also really liked the Hulk analogy. Though, I might suggest there is an equal chance that the Hulk might as easily be taken for another supernatural creature instead of a God. In fact, I remember a line from the T.V. "The Incredible Hulk Returns" which features both the Hulk and Thor.  While fighting, Thor makes the quote: "This will send you back to Hell you ugly troll."   IMDB has it listed at:  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095368/trivia?tab=qt&ref_=tt_trv_qu

Comment: @beichst : JasonBaker was the answerer, FYI.

Comment: @BlueDeeper - Basically, yeah. If you watch Agents of SHIELD, you'll see that even the Kree are thought of as "Angels who descended from the sky". These aliens visited earth so long back that their super powers made them look like gods to the humans at that time.

Comment: But from what I remember from reading my brother's Thor comics when I was little, Loki has never been a particularly strong guy, or particularly inclined to get into fistfights.  His specialty is being smart and mischievous.  I asked my brother recently if he remembered Thor and Loki ever really duking it out in the comics, and he said no.  Loki is smart enough to know that he can't win a physical conflict with Thor.  Thor is all about smashing stuff with a hammer and making lightning happen.  Loki is all about tricking people and outsmarting his brother.

Comment: So, basically, Hulk beat the snot out of Loki because Loki isn't hard to beat the snot out of, as supervillains go.

Comment: Also, I was always under the impression, when I read my brother's Thor comics, that Thor was very much a god - the god of thunder, to be exact.

Comment: And come to think of it, didn't a planet worship Hulk as a god in the Planet Hulk/World War Hulk storyline?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read Hulks potential of strength is practically limitless.
Who knows what he can accomplish given the circumstance.

Comment: This doesn’t really answer the question.

Comment: this answer is open-ended